# Android array not working - values missing

Tags: java, arrays

I have posted on here about a similar issue before and had no luck in solving it - so ended up working the program in a different way. However the same problem is happening on another part of my code and I was wondering if one of you guys would be kind enough to explain to me what is going wrong.

In basic terms the app declares an array at the start of the class
`double [][][] data = new double [5][250][250];`
The program then does some processing then sets the values to the data array in an iterative loop. If I read the values from the loop as they are set then they are all displayed as expected. However, when I read them later in the code only the first 5 items display.
Now here is the strange part: The array is not used anywhere else in the program, not once. Also this is happening for a string array I have setup in the same way, that is a [250][250] array and it also only shows the first 5. If I create a new array and copy the values into the second array and use the second array later then all the indexs work. It seems to be something to do with declaring the array at the start of the class.

Any help will be much appreciated.
I will try to clarify anything I have explained poorly.

Many thanks, Jack.

Code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/8EDLz99r

Comment: When exactly happens "later"? You have to add your code. And it's unclear why did you add `android` tag.

Comment: I have added a link to the code

Comment: pastebin link removed -- relink please.